# What does $\frac12({\ln b}^2-{\ln a}^2) $ equal to

Tags: logarithms

How can  $$\frac12({(\ln b)}^2-({\ln a})^2) $$
be equal to $$\frac12{\ln{(\frac ba)}{\ln (ab)}} $$

I know all the logarithmic properties, but I have no idea where to start

Comment: Hint:  $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$

Comment: I failed to notice that ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac12({(\ln b)}^2-({\ln a})^2)=\frac12(\ln b
+\ln a)(\ln b
-\ln a)=\frac12(\ln (ba))(\ln \frac{b}{a})$$